Первого и/или второго типа или типов?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в таких предложения правильно "типа" или "типов"? В интернете встречается примерно 50/50, а как все-таки правильно?
Заболевание, которое вызывается вирусом простого герпеса  первого и/или второго типа.
Герпес – это хроническое вирусное заболевание, которое вызвано вирусом простого герпеса первого и/или второго типов.
